# Is switching over to Amazon S3 for Drupal 7 image hosting worth it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, drupal-7

So I just have a quick question with regards to using *amazon s3*.

I have a small Drupal 7 site hosted on a VPS with not too much storage space. I put together the site for members of my School's Photographic Arts Committee to upload photos of School events and projects.

The full-quality photos are stored in a private folder on the server, and the images displayed on the site are watermarked 2048px width ones stored publicly.

I'm worried that I'm going to blow my storage space very fast, and I fear that I'm going to blow my not-really-exsistant budget on using amazon s3 with the module in Drupal.

So, I would like to know if it is a worthy investment using amazon s3, I'll be willing to spend +/- $5 dollars on it.

My monthly usage will include 3gigs worth of uploads and probably 20 gigs max downloads. Obviously slowly increasing.

Also, a bit confused about storage billing, do I have to pay for say my 50gigs worth storage from uploads from previous months, or just the 3 gigs of storage I used this month

PS: I live in South Africa and will probably use the Ireland S3 servers as they have the best latency.

Any feedback much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 may be a good option in your case, given your limited storage space.

You can calculate things fairly easily. Ignoring the 'requests' charge since it's tiny, here's the formula for Ireland:

(gb of storage * 0.3) + (avg image size * requests * 0.09) + (requests * 0.005/1000)

There are some volume discounts and some "first N transfer free", but this is a good ceiling, especially for a low-volume site as you mention. Also note storing the full-size images (and not downloading them) means only the first third of the formula matters. As an example, if you have 5gb in full-size images plus another 1gb in 350kb "2048px" images that sum to 10,000 image views per month:

full-size: 5*.03=.15
2048 hosting/downloads: (1*.03)+(0.00033*10000*.09)+(10000*.0004/10000)=0.3274

So, your monthly costs are about 50 cents.

What happens if your site is [slashdotted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect)? Imagine you get 10 million hits:

full-size: 5*.03=.15
2048 hosting/downloads: (1*.03)+(0.00033*10000000*.09)+(10000000*.004/10000)=301.03

So, your monthly cost is now over $300. (this is why [billing alarms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/gs_monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html) are important!)

Now, let's imagine you put cloudfront in front of S3 (which is a really good idea for several reasons) and look at the pricing in this scenario. (I've simplified the pricing here a little bit, and assuming nothing is loaded twice by the same browser, so no caching)

full-size: 5*.03=.15
2048 hosting/downloads: (1*.03)+(0.00033*10000000*.085)+(10000000*.009/10000)=289.53

so it saved about $10 but gave you better performance.

If you need more features (image resizing, for instance), you may want to consider a photo host like Flickr or Smugmug. They pay for bandwidth, which makes your costs more predictable.

Comment: Thanks you so much! That was very helpful and informative. Paying an extra 50 cents looks like it is definitely worth it!

Comment: I'll definitely set up those billing alarms though, not that I'll ever get slashdotted.